# How do I display the user login in a popup?

Tags: theming, javascript

When menu item "Login" is clicked, I want to display the login form as a popup. How can I achieve this?

I have looked into the following but with little luck. (Let me know if the answer is below and I am missing it.)

- modules: Overlay paths, Popup, Ajax login/register
- Code: `hook_admin_paths_alter()`

Any help will be great. I am looking for a clean pop up option that I can theme too.

Answer (score 4):

There is a module for that: [Modal Forms](http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms). Enable and configure it, you're just a checkbox away from modal login :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the [Fancy Login](http://drupal.org/project/fancy_login) module?

> Fancy Login adds javascript based, lightbox-style login functionality to your site. When the user clicks on any link that links to /user/login, they screen dims and a login box is created in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code, which requires the [Chaos Tool Suite (ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools/) module.

```php
function mymodule_user_login_block_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return _mymodule_form_ajax_callback($form, 'mymodule-user-login-block');
}
 
function _mymodule_form_ajax_callback($form, $wrapper_id) {
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#' . $wrapper_id, theme('status_messages') . drupal_render($form));
 
  $form_errors = form_get_errors();
  if (empty($form_errors)) {
    ctools_include('ajax');
    $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('checkout');
  }
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [TinyBox (Simple Splash)](http://drupal.org/project/tinybox) module.

> TinyBox module uses [TinyBox](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/), a lightweight and standalone modal window script. The main purpose of this module is to provide Splash Screen/Window as simple as possible.